# How to match number and dot sequence?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match to this string `2.1.34.5.1.` using this regex `^((\d{1,2}.)*)` by extracting a PDF File. However, I'm not getting to print this return. This is the output pdf page.

```
93

|
Page


1.5.4 Require Authentication for Single
-
```

What is happening here, what is matching is the `93` instead `1.5.4`.

```
import PyPDF2
import re
import sys
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_file = open('RH5-94.pdf','rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    IdCis = "(\d{1,2}.{0,1})*"
    Description = "(?<=Description:)(.*)(?=Rationale)"
    Rationale = "(?<=Rationale:)(.*)(?=Audit)"    
    textPage = read_pdf.getPage(0).extractText() 
    print(re.search(IdCis,textpage).group(0))
```

Comment: This code seems to work, the only advice I could make it to escape the period [i.e. ^((\d{1,2}\.)*)   instead of   ^((\d{1,2}.)*)  ]

Comment: yeah, I'm reading a PDF and each page the regex is executed, looking for this pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example `2.1.34.5.1.` ends with a `.` and your second `1.5.4` doesn't. For that reason, I am assuming that the sequence may or may not end with a `.`

Don't forget that to match a literal `.` you escape it with a backslash.

To ensure that there is at least one `.` in the sequence, `+` rather then `*` is used to match the group at least once.

```js
^(?:\d{1,2}\.)+\d{0,2}
```

Comment: Note that if you want to use `^` to match the start of a line you have to include the `re.MULTILINE` flag. Also, you may want to end the regex with a word boundary `\b` so that e.g. `1.234` is not matched.

Comment: Yeh, I already had removed `^` and added `MULTILINE`. Would be possible you explain that pattern?

Comment: It would be better to keep the `^` if the sequence always begins at the start of a line. The pattern means: `^` - assert start of line ; `(?:\d{1,2}\.)+` - match one or two digits followed by a `.`, one or more times ; `\d{0,2}` - match zero, one, or two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(\d{1,2}.{0,1})*
```

your problem is that your regex demands a dot at the end

Answer (score 0):

The reason `^((\d{1,2}.)*)` can match 93 is because the dot is not escaped and can therefore also match a digit. This part of the pattern `\d{1,2}.` matches at least 2 chars and at max 3 chars.

The `{1,2}` allows backtracking to match the 9 only to have the dot at the end matching the 3. It would not match a single digit for example.

As the pattern is optionally repeated using `*` it could also match an empty string, or in this case 2 digits.

**Note** that `{0,1}` can be written as `?`

You might also write the pattern as:

```
\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})+\.?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\.\d{1,2}` Match a dot and 1-2 digits
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat at least 1 time to not match a number without a dot
- `\.?` Match an optional dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/whTpi8/1)

Using whitespace boundaries with negative lookarounds to prevent partial matches:

```
(?<!\S)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})+\.?(?!\S)
```